# Hold Button to record a video with AVFoundation, Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, video, avfoundation, video-capture

I am trying to figure out how to record a video using `AVFoundation` in Swift. I have got as far as creating a custom camera but I only figured out how to take still pictures with it and I can't figure out how to record video. Hope you can help me figure this one out.

**I want to hold the** `takePhotoButton` **to record the video and then it will be previewed where I preview my current still photos. Your help will really help me continuing my project. Thanks a lot!**

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
class CameraViewController: UIViewController,AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {

let photoSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
    var captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    var videoDeviceInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput!
    var previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer()
    var frontCamera: Bool = false
    var captureDevice:AVCaptureDevice!
    var takePhoto = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        prepareCamera()
    }

    func prepareCamera() {
        captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto

        if let availableDevices = AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, position: .back).devices {
            captureDevice = availableDevices.first
            beginSession()
        } 
    }

    func frontCamera(_ front: Bool){
        let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices()

        do{
            try captureSession.removeInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device:captureDevice!)) 
        }catch{
            print("Error")
        }

        for device in devices!{
            if((device as AnyObject).hasMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)){
                if front{
                    if (device as AnyObject).position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.front {
                        captureDevice = device as? AVCaptureDevice

                        do{
                            try captureSession.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice!))
                        }catch{}
                        break
                    }
                }else{
                    if (device as AnyObject).position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.back {
                        captureDevice = device as? AVCaptureDevice

                        do{
                            try captureSession.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice!))
                        }catch{}
                        break
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func beginSession () {
        do {
            let captureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
            if let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession) {
            self.previewLayer = previewLayer
            containerView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer as? CALayer ?? CALayer())
            self.previewLayer.frame = self.view.layer.frame
            self.previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
            previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
            captureSession.startRunning()

            let dataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
            dataOutput.videoSettings = [(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as NSString):NSNumber(value:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)]

            dataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true

            if captureSession.canAddOutput(dataOutput) {
                captureSession.addOutput(dataOutput)

                photoSettings.isHighResolutionPhotoEnabled = true
                photoSettings.isAutoStillImageStabilizationEnabled = true
            }

            captureSession.commitConfiguration()

            let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.NightOut.captureQueue")
            dataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: queue) 
        }
    }
        @IBAction func takePhoto(_ sender: Any) {
            takePhoto = true

            photoSettings.isHighResolutionPhotoEnabled = true
            photoSettings.isAutoStillImageStabilizationEnabled = true
    }

    func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
        if takePhoto {
            takePhoto = false
            if let image = self.getImageFromSampleBuffer(buffer: sampleBuffer) {
                let photoVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PhotoVC") as! PhotoPreviewViewController

                photoVC.takenPhoto = image

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.present(photoVC, animated: true, completion: {
                        self.stopCaptureSession()
                    })
                }
            }  
        }
    }

    func getImageFromSampleBuffer (buffer:CMSampleBuffer) -> UIImage? {
        if let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(buffer) {
            let ciImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer)
            let context = CIContext()

            let imageRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer), height: CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer))

            if let image = context.createCGImage(ciImage, from: imageRect) {
                return UIImage(cgImage: image, scale: UIScreen.main.scale, orientation: .leftMirrored)
            }
    }
        return nil
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        self.captureSession.stopRunning()
    }

    func stopCaptureSession () {
        self.captureSession.stopRunning()

        if let inputs = captureSession.inputs as? [AVCaptureDeviceInput] {
            for input in inputs {
                self.captureSession.removeInput(input)
            }
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func DismissButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
            self.DismissButton.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: 0.8, y: 0.8)
        }, completion: { (finish) in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
                self.DismissButton.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            })
        })
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "Segue", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

To identify the holding down the button and releasing it, can be done in different ways. The easiest way would be adding a target for `UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside` and `UIControlEvents.TouchDown` for capture button like below.

```
aButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("holdRelease:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside);
aButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("HoldDown:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)

//target functions   
func HoldDown(sender:UIButton)
{
       // Start recording the video
}

func holdRelease(sender:UIButton)
{
       // Stop recording the video
}
```

There are other ways as well, like adding a long tap gesture recognizer to button or view and start/stop based on recognizer state. More info can be found here in another SO answer [UIButton with hold down action and release action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225475/uibutton-with-hold-down-action-and-release-action)

### Video Recording

You need to add `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` to your capture session and use the method `startRecordingToOutputFileURL` to start the video recording.

#### Things to notice

- Implement `AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate` method to identify the start and didFinish recording
- File path should be meaningful, Which means you should give the correct file path which your app has access.

Have this code inside `HoldDown()` method to start recording

> ```
>  let videoFileOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
>                 self.captureSession?.addOutput(videoFileOutput)
>  let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0] as URL
>  let filePath = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("tempMovie")
>  videoFileOutput.startRecording(toOutputFileURL: filePath, recordingDelegate: self)
> ```

to stop recording use `vidoeFileOutput.stopRecording()`

Comment: This is a very detailed and beautiful answer,But could you help me with a code snippet? i didn't understand how to implement the delegate and apples documents are not that helpful/i didn't understand them right.Sorry im still learning.Thanks

Comment: @RandomGeek I had a Swift camera code base on Github for my medium blog post tutorials. I have added record-video feature recently to it. Take a look at this Github [repo branch](https://github.com/rizwankce/Camera/tree/feature/record-video) for more info on how to implement recording video and play back. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks :) i will look into it.

Comment: i can't do this alone :( i will need help matching it into mine no matter what i try my app crashes and i fail to implement this...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput`. Add `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` to a capture session using `addOutput(_:)`

> Starting a Recording
>
> You start recording a QuickTime movie using
>   `startRecording(to:recordingDelegate:)`. You need to supply a
>   file-based URL and a delegate. The URL must not identify an existing
>   file, because the movie file output does not overwrite existing
>   resources. You must also have permission to write to the specified
>   location. The delegate must conform to the
>   `AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate` protocol, and must implement the
>   `fileOutput(_:didFinishRecordingTo:from:error:)`
>   method.

See [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html) for more info.

Comment: Could you maybe help me add this to my existing code? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`TouchDown` event giving me crash so I use following code and it's working fine on `swift5` `Xcode14.3.1`.

```
let longPressGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPressHandler(_:)))
        captureButton.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)

 @objc func longPressHandler(_ gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        if gesture.state == .began {
            print("Long press began")
            videoRecordingStated()
        } else if gesture.state == .ended {
            print("Long press ended")
            videoRecordingStoped()
        }
    }
```