# How to add a UILongPressGestureRecognizer release function

Tags: swift

I am using a long press gesture recognizer because without it if I click and release quickly on the buttons, the code doesn't execute properly. But with the long press gesture recognizer, my buttonUp function does not execute. How can I check if a finger is off the screen using long press gesture recognizer?

Comment: Please share some code that you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may refer to this if you want to have release action and hold down action in your [button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19225655/4287925)!

OR

You can check on the state of gesture in your long press [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50187878/4287925)!

OR

Handling a long-press gesture from [Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/handling_uikit_gestures/handling_long-press_gestures)

Hope it helps. 
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform any action with a single tap and long press you can add gestures into button this way:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var btn: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, #selector (tap))  //Tap function will call when user tap on button
    let longGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, #selector(long))  //Long function will call when user long press on button.
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    btn.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    btn.addGestureRecognizer(longGesture)
}

@objc func tap() {

    print("Tap happend")
}

@objc func long() {

    print("Long press")
}
```

This way you can add multiple methods for a single button and you just need Outlet for that button for that.

Comment: I needed a function to be called when the button gets released/untapped. The tapped thing is working fine.